# tmux send-keys confirm ssh tunnel is closed (after sending multiple commands to the remote host) before proceeding

Tags: shell-script, ssh, tmux, wait

there is an answer here about tmux using wait-for and LocalCommand to wait until the SSH connection is established before continuing, but I needed a way to have tmux wait for the ssh session to be closed (after using send-keys to the remote host in multiple commands) before continuing.

LocalCommand doesn't do this.

here's the question:

After:
1. opening a new tmux session
2. using send-keys to establish an ssh tunnel
3. sending multiple commands to the remote host using send-keys
4. closing the ssh tunnel using send-keys

How can I ensure bash waits until the terminal is ready to receive input before executing the next tmux send-keys command?

Answer (score 2):

How I ended up solving this:

```
rm ~/sesh.lock 2> /dev/null    # in case of previous failure
tmux new-session -d -s sesh
tmux send-keys -t sesh "ssh prod-srv-1" Enter
tmux send-keys -t sesh "cd /srv/www/api/bin" Enter
tmux send-keys -t sesh "echo api stop > ~/api_log.txt" Enter
tmux send-keys -t sesh exit Enter

while [ ! -e ~/sesh.lock ]
do
    tmux send-keys -t sesh "touch ~/sesh.lock" Enter
    sleep 0.1
done
tmux send-keys -t sesh "rm ~/sesh.lock 2> /dev/null" Enter 

tmux kill-session -t sesh
```